# Changing the method of checking passwords in Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel

in my windows app database I have a weirdly hashed password;
`BCRYPT$10$knwNGAey1Bh5lJ9/WNony.h3QqwPmqUoLa0cr0O7GT4oGGC/fmFCC`

where I can change code responsible for verifying passwords. I would like to modify it a bit to avoid this word 'BCRYPT';

Here is my changed code in clear PHP:

```php
$hash = 'BCRYPT$10$knwNGAey1Bh5lJ9/WNony.h3QqwPmqUoLa0cr0O7GT4oGGC/fmFCC'; # a JPremium hash
$hash = '$2y' .substr($hash, 6);
$password = 'qwerty8123'; # a password to verify

echo 'Is correct? (1 = yes, nothing = no) ' . password_verify($password, $hash);
```

I would only like to include these two lines.

Comment: Why do you care what hashed password looks like?

Comment: if you remove 'BCRYPT', perhaps you will face issues when user enter password and you will need to verify. May be it necessary for decrypting hashed password.

Comment: I can't remove this BCRYPT anyway, it was our Java developer who stated that his application would not work without it. I tried to login the user without changing this string but it throws invalid data

Comment: @Rattoo05 Honestly, why do you care what the *hashed* password looks like?